# Headless Chrome: Linked CSS Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, puppeteer, headless

I am trying to use the print-topdf functionality of headless chrome using the wrapper; PuppeteerJS. The HTML file I receive is built by pulling down the html of our webpage, adding the CSS, and then sending the file to a Puppeteer script for exporting.

When the page renders, all CSS is missing. Below is some code I wrote to diafnose the issue. It injects the CSS after being loaded into chrome, which works sans a few formatting issues.

```
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

  const browser = puppeteer.launch({headless: false}).then(function(browser){
      const page = browser.newPage().then(function(page){
          page.emulateMedia('screen');
          page.goto('url1....', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'}).then(function(){
            page.addStyleTag({url: 'url2...'}).then(function(){
              page.addStyleTag({url:'url3...' }).then(function(){
                page.addStyleTag({url: 'url4...'}).then(function(){
                    page.addStyleTag({url: 'url5...'}).then(function(){

                    });
                  });
                });
            });
          }); 
      });
  });
```

How can I ensure that, when I load the HTML file into headless Chrome (chromium), the CSS renders properly?

Comment: Have I understood correctly that the site looks normal outside of Puppeteer, and that it’s missing the CSS when you disable headless mode here? (By the way, you’re not returning any of your promises, which is why you have to nest them like that instead of [flattening them](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining#example-loadscript). You can probably use [`async`/`await`](https://javascript.info/async-await) to make it even simpler.)

Comment: @Aankhen Yes. The site is totally fine until headless chrome attempts to turn it into a pdf. Also, yeah I want to use async await, but I need to update my IDE so it doesn't throw syntax errors at me even though my JS version is correct /shrug

Comment: If you check the print preview in normal Chrome, does it have styles?

Comment: Yes. Opening the file normally produces expected results. When opened in headless, the css, although linked in the file, does not render.

@Aankhen

Comment: Really sorry, drawing a blank here… that’s all the variables I could think of. It sounds almost like the server is treating Chrome Headless differently. (Although you say ‘our webpage’, so maybe that’s not even a possibility.)

Comment: @Aankhen I still appreciate the comment. I should mention that even when not deployed on the server, headless chrome will still ignore css when exporting to pdf. It will work when headful, but not headless.

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors in headless mode?

Comment: @Aankhen None, BUT I think i've pinpointed the issue. Part of my HTML file is linking the css files hosted locally. It seems like when chrome is headless, it has trouble finding hosted files or even lacks permissions.

Comment: Ah! Are the original files on an HTTPS site? Older versions of Chrome Headless would fail to connect to sites that needed a client certificate (whereas newer versions do the same as the normal version and deliver the equivalent of a blank).

Comment: @Aankhen I think we've just solved this!! Way to go!!!

Comment: Oh, great! Does it work with a newer Chromium?

Comment: @Aankhen well no, but I can force chromium to allow access to the content I need even though it appears insecure to chromium.

Comment: Excellent! Glad it’s working.